# Is it possible to append the current date to filename is sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, filenames, output

I want the filename to be something like this top_queries_June.csv. Is it possible to do that in sqlite?

sqlite>.output (top_Queries + Select date('now')).csv

I run this batch file to create a file with the top queries.

### Batch file:

```
    sqlite3 mydb.db ".read x.sql"
```

### x.sql:

```
    .headers ON
    .mode csv
    .output Top_Queries + <current month>.csv
    select * from query;
    .quit
```

Comment: The `sqlite3` tool is interactive. Just use `.output top_queries_June.csv`.

Comment: @CL. to clarify, I am writing a script to automate file generation.

Comment: Then why don't you let that script automate the file name generation? (I.e., the same mechanism that changes the SQL parameters should also change the file name.)

Comment: How do you generate `query`?

Comment: @CL.'query' is a table within the database (mydb.db)

Comment: And that name is always the same for different months?

Comment: @CL. No, I will be creating this report on a monthly basis so want to add the month name to the filename

Comment: Is the name of that table always the same (i.e., `query`) for different months?

Comment: @CL.yes, it will remain the same

Answer (score 1):

As @CL. already pointed out the sqlite3 command line utility is not flexible enough to do this. You appear to be using some kind of shell to execute sqlite3. Most shells support a feature called "here document" and the `sqlite3` utility supports reading commands from a pipe. Using these you can inline the `x.sql` file into your shell script. In a POSIX compatible shell your code could look like this:

```
DATE=`date -I`
sqlite3 mydb.db <<EOF
.headers ON
.mode csv
.output Top_Queries${DATE}.csv
select * from query;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Well - actually you can - but it's a bit clumsy.

1. Build the output file name using a variable in a temporary table
2. Dump the file name into a SQL file
3. Read the expression dump to set the output file with datetime stamp

```sql
-- Using temporary variables
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS variables;

CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    Variables 
    (
        name    TEXT PRIMARY KEY
    ,   value   TEXT
    );

-- Insert time stamp + file stub
REPLACE INTO variables 
    VALUES 
    ('release', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
,   ('now_file', strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) )
;

-- Build file name for output
.output redirect.sql

SELECT
        '.output file_' || value || '.txt'
FROM
        variables
WHERE
        name = 'now_file';
.output

-- Set output file to file name with date stamp
.read redirect.sql

SELECT
        *
FROM
        variables;
.output
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked well but had issues around the file name due to needing to get to a specific directory that had spaces in the names so found that this fixed the problem.

'.output ' || '''C:\Users\800\OneDrive - OD1\Documents\Finance\Reporting\OR Costs\SQL\AA_Output_Files\OP_Basic_Connections_2324_'|| value ||'.txt'''

Comment: It looks like you're trying to comment on someone else's answer. You submitted a separate answer instead.  Is that what you intended? Maybe you meant to click "Add a comment"?